# C#: консольное приложение - ошибка

Tags: c#

Добрый день.

Я на C# написал консольное приложение, которое просто скачивает файл с ресурса в указанную в конфиге папку.

Получилась интересная ситуация - запускаю (из Visual Studio) **F5 (в отладке)** - работает все нормально, как положено. Но если я запускаю через **Ctrl+F5** - пишет "`указанный путь был использован при запуске cmd.exe в качестве текущей папки. cmd не поддерживает пути UNC`..." после чего программа валится, т.к. она пытается читать файл настроек НЕ из каталога программы а из папки Windows.

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Я поставил задачу через  **Постановщик задач**, который запускает прогу раз в 1 час, и он запускает - но вылетает такая ошибка, и программа валится.

**Интересно,что если прогу запускать просто через exe-файл, все работает нормально.**

**Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы программа запускалась через шедулер нормально?**

С уважением, Л.

Comment: Ты пробовал указывать локальный путь, типа "C:\..."? Сдается мне, что процессу, запущенного из постановщика задач, не разрешено использовать сетевые пути.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Настройки приложения (если это не app.config, а отдельный файл, в который приложение будет сохранять свои параметры) лучше хранить в директории пользователя, т.к. в директории приложения может не быть соответствующих прав на запись файлов.

Директорию пользователя, где у приложения точно есть права на запись, можно получить так:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Но нужно иметь в виду, что под другим пользователем Windows это будет другая директория.

Comment: Замечательный вариант. Как вариант, можно еще использовать Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй для формирования пути использовать
[AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Это вернет тебе путь к директории, где реально лежит твой exe, а не где его рабочая папка.